# Node.JS how to decode ISO-8859-1 into UTF-8?

Tags: node.js, utf-8, character-encoding, iconv

I'm querying a database in ISO-8859-1 but since node runs in UTF8 mode, i must convert the data being returned this particular DBMS.

I tried iconv but I can't figure out how to get the desired output.
For example, i got 0xc2 0x80 when I expected 0xe2 0x82 0xac to be returned.

```
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');

var buffer = Buffer.from([0x80]);
var str = iconv.decode(buffer, 'iso-8859-1');
console.log({str});
console.log(new Buffer(str, 'utf8'));
iconv.encode(new Buffer('€','utf8'),'iso-8859-1');

/*
Which outputs
{ str: '' }
<Buffer c2 80>*/
```

- In UTF8 € is represented by 0xe2 0x82 0xac
- In ISO-8859-1 is represented by 0x80

**Updates:**

- Expected value for € is 0xe2 0x82 0xac and not 0xdb as I mentioned initially by mistake
- As stated in the comments ISO-8859-1 doesn't contain a € character.

Comment: ‘*In UTF8 € is represented by 0xDB*’ No, it’s `0xe2 0x82 0xac`. `0xc2 0x80` on the other hand is a control character that sometimes renders *a bit like* € (). ISO 8859-1 doesn’t even have a €.

Comment: … You’re trying to convert something that doesn’t exist. Are you sure about the source encoding? ISO 8859-**15** has a €, but it’s at `0xa5`. Some Windows encodings, e.g. *windows-1252/latin1* have € at `0x80`.

Comment: The database column is ISO-8859-1 which is also the default dB encoding. Using ibexpert to inspect the data I see that € is being represented as 0x80 in the hex viewer

Comment: That’s… just wrong. Someone has inserted bad data into that database. ISO 8859-1 doesn’t have a €, and `0x80` isn’t assigned in ISO 8859-1. If you do want it to work that way you’ll have to either manually replace it, or find an encoding that happens to match, without messing up any other characters.

Comment: FYI: [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (also called latin1).  No €. 0x80 is undefined.

Comment: That Wikipedia page has an interesting titbit: ‘*The Windows-1252 code page coincides with ISO-8859-1 for all codes except the range 128 to 159 (hex 80 to 9F), where the little-used C1 controls are replaced with additional characters including all the missing characters provided by ISO-8859-15. It is very common to mislabel Windows-1252 text as being in ISO-8859-1.*’

Comment: Minor correction to my comment.  `ISO 8859-1` has 0x80 undefined.  `ISO-8859-1` (extra hyphen) adds the C0 and C1 control codes so 0x80 is defined, just not as €.  That tidbit is in that page as well.

Comment: I realize that IBEXPERT shows the blob preview in ANSI.
Maybe this justifies why I'm seeing 0x80 on the hex representation?

Comment: That's weird, In terms of character set i'm 100% sure that the databae is using IS88859_1. The weird part is that IBEXPERT shows up the preview in ANSI which according to wikipedia stands for "Windows-1252".  This is why I'm seeing  € represented as 0x80 (http://ascii-table.com/ansi-codes.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments above I realize that despite of having a character set of "ISO8859_1" in my database, under the hood IBEXPERT is using and presenting me the data in WINDOWS-1252 (known as ANSI) encoding, which explains why I was seeing 0x80 in their HEX viewer.

Maybe WINDOWS-1252 extends somehow the ISO8859_1 character set??

For example:
Running the code below works fine:
€ is correctly decoded.

```
var str = iconv.decode(buffer, 'WINDOWS-1252');
console.log({str});
console.log(new Buffer(str, 'utf8'));
var str2 = iconv.encode(new Buffer('€','utf8'),'WINDOWS-1252');
console.log({strEncoded: str2})
/*
{ str: '€' }
<Buffer e2 82 ac>
{ strEncoded: <Buffer 80> }
* */
```

The weird part is that my database query which uses **node-firebirdlib-fbclient** to communicate with my firebird database resolves with a UTF8 character that cannot be represented in UTF8 as you can see by the symbol value which is ' ' which translate into 0xc2 0x80.

```
   { idNumber: 1,
     id: 'EUR',
     taxPercentage: 1,
     isDefault: -1,
     accountNumber: null,
     dontUse: false,
     symbol: '' },
  eur: <Buffer c2 80> }
```

eur: is being output by `console.log(new Buffer(result.symbol,'utf8'))`

And decoding this from utf8 to 'WINDOWS-1252' with the following command 
`iconv.decode(Buffer.from(currency.symbol, 'utf8'), 'WINDOWS-1252')` returns

...
 "defaultCurrency": {
        "id": "EUR",
        **"symbol": "Â€",**
        "label": "EUR"
    }...